# jquery .animate works in jsfidle, will not work in website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement this simple jquery [code](http://jsfiddle.net/B2W3S) into my website, I can not make it work!

Here is whole html code (everything is the same as in the WORKING jsfiddle version, however it will not work):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

<style>
    div#test {
        background: #b977d1;
        margin: 3px;
        width: 150px;
        height: 20px;
        float: right;
        display: none;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    button#aa {
        float: right;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#aa").click(function () {
    $("div#test").animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    });;
});

</script>

<div id="test">TEST das das dsa</div>
<button id="aa">Toggle</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting very frustrated with this :P

If anyone can help me with this, I will be more than thankful! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your jquery inside `$(document).ready()` jsfiddle do this automatically
try this:

```
$(document).ready(funciton(){
    $("#aa").click(function () {
        $("div#test").animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        });;
    });
});
```

Comment: WoW! it works! solution ready after 1minute.. i spent on it like 1 hour and could not work it out!
Thank you so much!!!

Comment: glad to help you! remind to accept the answer to help other guys with your same problem @user3327001

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code inside DOM ready handler to make sure that Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

This step has been done automatically by `jsFiddle` when you include jQuery library.

```
$(function(){
    $("#aa").click(function () {
        $("div#test").animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        });;
    });
});
```

If you want to run your code once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready, put your code inside `$(window).load(function() { ... })`

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    $("#aa").click(function () {
        $("div#test").animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        });;
    });
})
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your effort! it all works fine and also I will know what to do in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your jQuery code in callback of the `ready` function.

```
$(function() {
 // when the document is ready
 // here, your code
});
```

Comment: Thank you for a working solution! :)